# Load pickle file(comes from python3) in python2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle

I have a pickle file, with

```
>>> with open("wikilinks.pickle", "rb") as f:
...     titles, links = pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> len(titles)
13421
```

I can load it in python3.
However, when I try to load it in python2, I get this message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 886, in load_proto
    raise ValueError, "unsupported pickle protocol: %d" % proto
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

So how to load it in python2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [default pickling protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html#pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL) used by default in Python 3 is incompatible with the protocol used by Python 2. However, if you can modify the code that produces `wikilink.pickle`, you can tell it to use one of the earlier protocols (0, 1, or 2) which Python 2 will understand just fine.

Be warned, though, that Python 3 strings will come up as Unicode strings in Python 2, which may be surprising in some use cases.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 17:23:49) 
[GCC 4.9.0 20140507 (prerelease)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps([1, 2, 'abc'], 2)
b'\x80\x02]q\x00(K\x01K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00abcq\x01e.'
>>> 
$ python 
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  1 2014, 17:30:21) 
[GCC 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cPickle
>>> cPickle.loads('\x80\x02]q\x00(K\x01K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00abcq\x01e.')
[1, 2, u'abc']
```

Comment: so how to slove the unicode problem?

Comment: @ChaoZhang Convert the Unicode strings to utf8, or update the code to deal with them.

Comment: i call python2 to convert unicode and long integer after python3 process, thus the output pickle file can use in python2 system directly, lol

Answer (score 37):

Read in python3 and save it as python2 format

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pickle

with open("a.pkl", "rb") as f:
    w = pickle.load(f)

pickle.dump(w, open("a_py2.pkl","wb"), protocol=2)
```

Then you can load `a_py2.pkl` in python2.